# when to use parenthesis in concatenation in php

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I am trying to log some debug messages when a non 200 response is received. The response has a `response` property which can either be a string or it can it self be a `object` with a message property.

Here is my log statement:

```
\Log::info('Caller non 200 response received. \nMessage' .  is_object($response->response)?$response->response->message : $response->response);
```

And I get

> Trying to get property of non-object

at the above mentioned line. I changed it to:

```
\Log::info('Caller non 200 response received. \nMessage' .  (is_object($response->response)?$response->response->message : $response->response) );
```

Notice the parenthesis around the ternary operator, and it works. What am I missing?

Also for this scenario I am getting `false` returned from the `is_object` call.

Comment: If `is_object($response->response)` is false, adding a concatenation before it before the ternary operator, it makes the case true, and tries to use `$response->response->message` when the `is_object` was actually false on your test for containing a response property.

Comment: it has a response property @JonStirling.. and it has a string value.

Comment: I don't understand @Ultimater how putting a concatenation before the ternary operator makes the case true?

Comment: Because the PHP engine read it left to right and treats it as: `('Caller non 200 response received. \nMessage' .  is_object($response->response))? ... : ...` which is always true.

Comment: @Ultimater Ah, of course. Worth adding an answer :)

Comment: Here's a PHP fiddle demonstrating the concept: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fpuh-142q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it turns out that when you do:

```
$val = 'some string ' . is_object($notObj) ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

will evaluate `$val` to ***some string yes*** instead of `no`, given that `$notObj` is not an object and `is_object` will return `false`.

Because we are concatenating the string with the output of `is_object`, that's why that evaluates to `true`.

To overcome that you need to put parenthesis around the ternary operator like this:

```
$val = 'some string ' . (is_object($notObj) ? 'yes' : 'no')
```

Now this will successfully evaluate `$val` to ***some string no***.

Thanks to @Ultimater for explaining this.